# Breathing Capability Up Really High

Tags: science-based, biology, geography, altitude

So my setting is a bunch of islands in the sky above an ocean, and I've toyed with the idea of having a barrier around them so I don't have to Science This Out, but having just discovered this magical place, I thought I'd shoot my shot.

I've been trying to decide how high above the water they can be before the people living there would have some major issues. I tried looking up what it's like to live in high-altitude places, but I'm trying to figure out how high I can place my islands before everyone's puking up spleens or bleeding out their armpits.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding! I hope that you will find your experience on this site both interesting and useful. You may want to take the [tour] and peruse the [help] in order to become better acquainted with the rules and expectations of this site. In particular, what research have you done before asking this question? Have you used your favorite search engine to see if the question has already been asked? Unfortunately, the question is very obviously missing *all* the relevant data. Basically, the question doen't give any input numbers whatsoever, yet it requests a numerical answer.

Comment: You need to describe your planet and its atmosphere before we can answer this. Surface gravity and the mixture of gasses in the atmosphere are the key details.

Comment: I can't find it just now, but very similar questions have been asked. If you search for maximum altitude for breathing you should start to see some hits. If you Google for minimum pressure for breathing you will find some good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 5,950 meters

Because no data has been given regarding *where* and *what* your planet is like, I'm going to go with the highest altitude possible to live on Earth, and assume that the inhabitants of your islands are humans.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_high_altitude_on_humans#:%7E:text=Humans%20have%20survived%20for%20two,5%2C100%20m%20(16%2C700%20ft).):

5,100m - highest permanent settlement of humans

Above 5,500m - increased risk of permanent brain damage

Above 7,500 - humans will start to see serious effects, including difficulties with sleep and digestion

Above 8,000m - known as the "death zone" because it's believed to be virtually impossible for humans to survive there

If you want to push your luck, I'd go for the highest altitude where humans reportedly lived and did not die: 5,950m.

> Humans have survived for two years at 5,950 m (19,520 ft, 475 millibars of atmospheric pressure), which is the highest recorded permanently tolerable altitude; the highest permanent settlement known, La Rinconada, is at 5,100 m (16,700 ft)

Although if your inhabitants are settled on these islands long term, chances are they've adapted to the higher altitudes. Maybe they even breathe nitrogen. So evolutionarily, anything is possible.